# Issue with Skype freezing on M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, skype, apple-silicon

macOS Ventura 13.4 (22F66)

Skype UI freezing after long run or after hibernate.
Cleaning and reinstalling Skype app not fix issue. Second clean reinstall macOS have not fixed this issue.

Comment: It’s likely a bug. File a report with Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently a known issue (according to Apple, but Microsoft haven't admitted this), but has been going on for 6+ months and Microsoft don't appear to be interested in solving it.

I've reported it as an issue in the insider builds 10+ times over the last 6 months and made some detailed reports, but haven't got any response.

See threads like this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/issue-with-skype-freezing-on-m2-macbook-pro-after/bff687a4-2242-42bf-b1d5-290931c6520a

The latest case I ran into, taking a sample with activity monitor it seems like it's deadlocking the main/UI thread in an observer within libRtmMediaStack when trying to make a cross-process call.

```
Call graph:
    2424 Thread_877103   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 2424 start  (in dyld) + 2236  [0x19c8fbf28]
    +   2424 ???  (in Skype Helper (Renderer))  load address 0x10478c000 + 0x960  [0x10478c960]
    +     2424 ElectronMain  (in Electron Framework) + 128  [0x113cdf18c]
    +       2424 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*)  (in Electron Framework) + 12484  [0x113f5b1e8]
    +         2424 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*)  (in Electron Framework) + 11256  [0x113f5ad1c]
    +           2424 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*)  (in Electron Framework) + 16396  [0x113f5c130]
    +             2424 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*)  (in Electron Framework) + 14120  [0x113f5b84c]
    +               2424 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*)  (in Electron Framework) + 27772104  [0x11774e874]
    +                 2424 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*)  (in Electron Framework) + 4964396  [0x11618e3d8]
    +                   2424 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*)  (in Electron Framework) + 5163756  [0x1161bee98]
    +                     2424 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*)  (in Electron Framework) + 5394784  [0x1161f750c]
    +                       2424 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*)  (in Electron Framework) + 5399852  [0x1161f88d8]
    +                         2424 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]  (in Foundation) + 212  [0x19dca9fcc]
    +                           2424 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 612  [0x19cd304b8]
    +                             2424 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 828  [0x19cd30f48]
    +                               2424 __CFRunLoopDoSources0  (in CoreFoundation) + 244  [0x19cd32340]
    +                                 2424 __CFRunLoopDoSource0  (in CoreFoundation) + 176  [0x19cd325d0]
    +                                   2424 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__  (in CoreFoundation) + 28  [0x19cd3263c]
    +                                     2424 __NSThreadPerformPerform  (in Foundation) + 264  [0x19dcc6c64]
    +                                       2424 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]  (in Foundation) + 88  [0x19dc568f4]
    +                                         2424 _CFXNotificationPost  (in CoreFoundation) + 704  [0x19ccf84cc]
    +                                           2424 _CFXRegistrationPost  (in CoreFoundation) + 440  [0x19cdc2e34]
    +                                             2424 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke  (in CoreFoundation) + 88  [0x19cdc2eec]
    +                                               2424 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__  (in CoreFoundation) + 148  [0x19cd27180]
    +                                                 2424 ???  (in libRtmMediaStack.dylib)  load address 0x123800000 + 0xedf7cc  [0x1246df7cc]
    +                                                   2424 ???  (in libRtmMediaStack.dylib)  load address 0x123800000 + 0xedfa10  [0x1246dfa10]
    +                                                     2424 ???  (in libRtmMediaStack.dylib)  load address 0x123800000 + 0xf08758  [0x124708758]
    +                                                       2424 ???  (in libRtmMediaStack.dylib)  load address 0x123800000 + 0xf09604  [0x124709604]
    +                                                         2424 ???  (in libRtmMediaStack.dylib)  load address 0x123800000 + 0xf09280  [0x124709280]
    +                                                           2424 ???  (in libRtmMediaStack.dylib)  load address 0x123800000 + 0xf03788  [0x124703788]
    +                                                             2424 _NSXPCDistantObjectSimpleMessageSend1  (in Foundation) + 60  [0x19dc709e8]
    +                                                               2424 -[NSXPCConnection _sendSelector:withProxy:arg1:]  (in Foundation) + 116  [0x19dc70ab4]
    +                                                                 2424 -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]  (in Foundation) + 2200  [0x19dc69314]
    +                                                                   2424 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_WAITING_FOR_A_SYNCHRONOUS_REPLY__  (in Foundation) + 16  [0x19dc6b400]
    +                                                                     2424 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync  (in libxpc.dylib) + 264  [0x19c995c3c]
    +                                                                       2424 dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 60  [0x19cabfd88]
    +                                                                         2424 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 548  [0x19cabf9f8]
    +                                                                           2424 mach_msg  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 24  [0x19cc14290]
    +                                                                             2424 mach_msg_overwrite  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 604  [0x19cc1cb78]
    +                                                                               2424 mach_msg2_internal  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 80  [0x19cc26240]
    +                                                                                 2424 mach_msg2_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x19cc13f14]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had just reinstall 2 macbook air with M1 this week for my boss
and I had suffered the same issues
Im not sure is the solution is right or not. or just temp solution
but it did solved the issue

1. **pmset** : I had tried " pmset " to disable the sleep  mode .
   (  pmset -g sleep 0  )
   I know this is not a good solution but fine it solved the issue and work well except the battery resource .
2. **Switch skype APP to rosseta mode**
   and then I found that it seems that the SLEEP MODE's  operation Mechanism is  different between apple sillcon and intelx86
   well ,so I had tried to switch skype APP to rosseta mode and it works but it seems a little bit slow ( might be a illusion)
   oh ~ skype preview edition for apple sillcon  is not work for me
   and its weird  skype works fine  if I update /upgrade the system to the lasted  whenever the system notified me  in the same envirement

but if I use the factory seeting (I mean  reinstall the whole system ) and then install the skype the skype is not workable

just for your information , cause I had digged everywhere
so wish could help someone suffering the same issue